# Java Regex How would you stick numbers into a String at certain positions

Tags: java, regex

I'm using a tool that allows for some java code, but it has special syntax for if statements and a few other methods including the date transformation methods. 
As a result of this limitation, I have to use RegEx to solve my issue.

The date format should be MMddyyyy (01012014 for Jan 1 2014). The problem is that it's missing the 0's so it looks like "112014" instead of "01012014".

There are a few possible date types to look out for.

```
112014   (Jan 1 2014)
1012014  (Jan 1 2014)
```

[edit: this first case is weird. Sometimes they have the day as a single digit, other times they put it as two digits. so Jan 1 2014 is either 112014 OR 1012014]

```
1102014  (Jan 10 2014)
10012014  (Oct 1 2014)
10102014 (Oct 10 2014)
```

The first 3 would need to be changed to:

```
01012014
01102014
10012014
```

I can do multiple nested if statements, so I could write

```
if date length == 6 do something
else if date length == 7 do something else
else whatever
```

Comment: show code, what have you tried? Why not use DateTimeConverting utility? What do you mean by tool that allows use of java code?

Comment: What about `1112014`? Is that Nov 1 or Jan 11? Answer: who knows?! You can't distinguish them, so your data is no good.

Comment: @Bohemian You brought up a good point. I checked the data more carefully and it turns out that when that happens, they put a 0 for the day, so it would be 1112014 or 11012014

Comment: Why don't "they" put leading zeroes for all fields in all records? It's actually less work for them. Sometimes the best solution is to push back on the data provider and ask for quality data, instead of trying to fix their mess.

Comment: @Vogel612 I'm using Talend, a data transformation tool. They have a mapping component that lets you map one field to another field. Sometimes a bit of code is required so they have an expression editor that lets you use some java. However the use is pretty limited.

Comment: @Bohemian I agree they should put the leading 0's in, but our company doesn't want to bother them because they're generating really good business so my company asked me to just deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its just a 6 or 7 issue, I would use a 2 regex substitution.
This asumes that if 7, the month is missing the 0.

pseudocode:

if find: `^(\d)(\d{2}\d{4})$` replace `0\1\2`
else
if find: `^(\d)(\d\d{4})$` replace `0\1`+`0\2`